# Self-replicating code, how to implement different behavior in first iteration vs following ones?

Tags: c

So I'm having a tough time with a school project. The goal is to make a self-replicating code, name Sully.c. That program must output it's own source code (it's a quine) into a program named Sully_x.c, where x is an integer in the source code, then compile said program and execute it iff x > 0. x must decrement from one copy to the next, but not from the original Sully.c to Sully_5.c.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int k = 5;
#define F1 int main(void){int fd = open("Sully_5.c", 0);if(fd != -1){close(fd);k-=1;}char buff[62];(sprintf)(buff, "Sully_%d.c", k);FILE *f = fopen(buff, "w");fprintf(f, "#include <fcntl.h>\n#include <stdio.h>\n#include <stdlib.h>\n#include <unistd.h>\nint k = %d;\n#define F1 %s\n#define F2(x) #x\n#define F3(x) F2(x)\nconst char *s = F3(F1);\nF1\n", k, s);fclose(f);(sprintf)(buff, "gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror Sully_%d.c -o Sully_%d", k, k);system(buff);if (k != 0){(sprintf)(buff, "./Sully_%d", k);system(buff);}return 0;}
#define F2(x) #x
#define F3(x) F2(x)
const char *s = F3(F1);
F1
```

That code works, and checks all the requirements for the program. However, I'm using a method that checks something other than the code itself -> I'm checking if sully_5.c already exists or not. If it doesn't, x doesn't move, if it does, then it is decremented.
Another method would have been to use argv[0] or the macro `__FILE__`, but both these options are explicitly forbidden for the assignment and considered cheating.

But, apparently there are other methods that doesn't require any of the above technique. I can't think of any, because if Sully.c and Sully_5.c need different behaviors but the same source code, than there must be an external variable that needs to influence the code behavior, or so is my hypothesis.

Am I right? Wrong? How else could this be done?

Comment: envornment variable + exec yourself

Comment: Yes, but an env variable is external to the code. I'm looking for a behavior that would rely only on the source code and nothing else.

Comment: perhaps libtcc (https://github.com/LuaDist/tcc/blob/master/tests/libtcc_test.c) would be of interest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... there must be an  external variable that needs to influence the code behavior
>
> How else could this be done?

- You can define or not some preprocessing variables (e.g. `-Daze` or `-Daze=12` etc) to generate a different code using conditional compilation without changing the source
- The execution can also use the argument(s) given to the program when it is run to change its behavior

Comment: Arguments are explicitly forbidden for this assignment though

Comment: @JonNimrod this is not indicated in the question, what about to edit it to add that requirement ?

Comment: Yep, sorry about that. However that conditional compilation sounds interesting, I'm going to look into it.

Comment: Yeah conditional compilation does work, but I can't stringify the define so I had to revert to the traditional quine writing which is much more lengthy. Thanks  still.